# Compiling Snort for OpenWRT

Tags: router, openwrt, make, snort

I'm trying to install Snort on an OpenWRT VM. I followed the instructions on the [Snort homepage](https://www.snort.org/) and it looks like it requires the `make` tool for compiling the code:

```
./configure --enable-sourcefire; make; sudo make install
```

Problem is - I don't have `make` on the OpenWRT (and in this case there's no Snort distribution for OpenWRT).

I'm trying to understand how to install `make` on OpenWRT, but can't find the correct way to do it so far.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the easiest way is to use `opkg` which I tried at the beginning as follows:

```
opkg install snort
```

But the `snort` package was not found. But after I updated `opkg` it worked:

```
opkg update
opkg install snort
```